# No Answer Should Answer

Tags: riddle, rhyme, story, knowledge

One day, the King ordered me to visit the city of NASA to find a rare herb to cure his daughter's illness. However, upon arriving at the city's gate, a guard stopped me.

"Hello, why are you here?" started the guard.

"I was sent by the King to find the magic herb."

"Well, but you can't," the guard explained, "the herb you are talking about is wanted by lots of people, therefore, the new policy states that only the citizens here may use it. Moreover, since too many robbers are around recently, I am ordered to forbid any outsiders from entering the city."

"Are you trying to stop an envoy of the King?" I replied.

"All right. To prove you are the King's envoy, and since envoys are geniuses, you must name all the **seven creatures** living in this city. Now!"

"Whaaat? No way. Do you think I am a genius or a psychic? It's impossible."

"Aha, it is indeed. But the clues are on the wall over there"

Curious, I immediately walked to the wall pointed by the guard. Riddles! Could it be worse? Since riddles are my only weakness (well, to be honest, dragons too), I take a photo of it and publish it to P.SE., with the hope that someone can crack it.

> A chameleon, looks quite purple
>   With a hammer, it's rather immortal
>
> In France, it looks like two
>   And Russ is one of the few
>
> It's a quick Welsh wing
>   4152 he once did sing
>
> It's the continuation in the Alp'bet
>   The grass grow you should not let!
>
> It's the shortest among the it's folks
>   Just a letter and two simple strokes
>
> It's the perfect middle of the list
>   It is known for its ability to resist
>
> It's red, it's cardinal, it's expensive
>   And it's the beginning of the offensive

Can anyone help the princess? Well, of course, it's me. I mean, can anyone help me figuring out the 'seven creatures' so that I can pass the guard?

PS: I cannot fly, no other entrances exist, and the use of 4-dimensional spaces is strictly forbidden. No [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) here.

Comment: ***HER*** daughter?

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Are you assuming the King's gender? :p jk, it's an error. Any grammatical or logical edits are welcome, as long as it doesn't change the substance nor the rhymes.

Comment: What about 5-dimensional space (or 11 for that matter)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The 'seven creatures' are

> seven members of Puzzling SE, namely the ones with the all time highest reputation

A chameleon, looks quite purple
With a hammer, it's rather immortal

> [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor): purple chameleon Randall from Monster Inc, and Thor from the Marvel Universe

In France, it looks like two
And Russ is one of the few

> [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi): 'Two' in french is 'deux', 'sovi' might refer to the *sovi*et union, which covered large parts of today's *Russ*land.

It's a quick Welsh wing
4152 he once did sing

> [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan): Gareth Bale is referred to as the [Welsh Wing Wizard](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/1563343-gareth-bale-where-did-it-all-go-right-for-tottenhams-welsh-wing-wizard?m=0), `Four Five One Two` is an album of Chris McCaughan's band Sundowner

It's the continuation in the Alp'bet 
The grass grow you should not let!

> [Gamow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/8874/gamow): Ga is the continuation of *Alp*ha, *Bet*a, *Ga*mma; and you *mow* the grass to stop growing it.

It's the shortest among the it's folks
Just a letter and two simple strokes

> [f''](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12408/f): pretty self-explanatory.

It's the perfect middle of the list
It is known for its ability to resist

> [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9860/m-oehm): M is the middle letter of the alphabet, Ohm the unit of electrical resistance

It's red, it's cardinal, it's expensive 
And it's the beginning of the offensive

> [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio): A ruby is red and expensive, o is the first letter of 'offensive'

Finally the title hints that

> none of the users listed above should answer the question. Probably because they've got too much reputation already ;)

Comment: YES! I feel that if they answer their own question, it's unfair. Plus, they are inside the city, so if they can come out to help me, why don't they just bring the herbs? :D By the way, what clue makes this puzzle so easy? (PS: Alp, Bet,???)

Comment: Just figured out the Alp'bet! The first clue was the first I figured out, probably because there was a similar clue for that specific 'creature' before. From there on it was rather easy, matching 'creatures' with the clues.

Comment: Inspected by ⑦. Puzzle and answer: approved.

Comment: Damn. I'm number 8 :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I initially wanted to make it 8, but then I realized you were mentioned in too many other puzzles, including one of mine before (the one about a bigger family) and the famous Puzzling Trophy. Sorry! :D

Comment: @WilliamNathanael no worries :P and hey 7 is a lucky number :P

Comment: Upvoted because you're not one of the 7 :-P